# AWS Network Load Balancer not forwarding connection to EC2 instances

Tags: c, amazon-web-services, sockets, tcp, load-balancing

I am trying to establish a connection between a local client program and a server program running on an AWS EC2 instance. When I'm directly connecting through the public IP address of the EC2 instance, I face no problem and the connection is established as expected (I am printing out the IP address of the connected server to check whether the connection proceeds correctly or not)

However, when I add the EC2 instance to a Network Load Balancer and pass the NLB's IP while running the client program, then the connection that is being established is between the client program and the Load Balancer, and not the server program (as suggested by the IP address printed). I was expecting that the Load Balancer would forward the connection to the server and the connection would be established, but apparently, it's not the case

Why is it so? And how to solve this and get the desired result (i.e. the connection to be between the client and server program as it was happening without the load balancer)

EDIT: This does not seem to be a problem with load balancer configuration or permissions, as it works well when I run a simple Web Application on an Apache server on the EC2 instances (instead of the C server program). I guess the client and server programs are not establishing the connection in the desired manner. What needs to be done?

This is my client program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"

int OpenConnection(const char *hostname, int port) {
    int sd;
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    if ( (host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL )
    {
        printf("Could not find host\n");
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    else {
      printf("Succesfully found host - %s\n", host->h_name);
    }

    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)(host->h_addr);
    if ( connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )
    {
        printf("Connection Failed\n");
        close(sd);
        perror(hostname);
        abort();
    }
    else {
      char* address = inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr);
      printf("Connection Succesful at socket %d\n", sd);
      printf("%s\n", address);
      printf("Port is: %d\n", ntohs(addr.sin_port));
    }
    return sd;
}

int main(int args, char* argv[]) {
  char* hostname = argv[1];
  char* port = argv[2];
  int portnum = atoi(port);

  int server;
  server = OpenConnection(hostname, portnum);

  close(server);
  return 0;
}
```

And this is my server program

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"

#define FAIL    -1

int OpenListener(int port) {
    int sd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 ) {
        perror("can't bind port");
        printf("Cannot bind port\n");
        abort();
    }
    else  printf("Port bind Succesful\n");


    if (listen(sd, 10) != 0 ) {
        perror("Can't configure listening port");
        abort();
    }
    else printf("Configured listening port\n");

    return sd;
}


int isRoot() {
    if (getuid() != 0) return 0;
    else return 1;
}

int main(int args, char *argv[]) {
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    char *portnum;

    if(!isRoot()) {
        printf("This program must be run as root/sudo user!!");
        exit(0);
    }

    if (args != 2 ) {
        printf("Usage: %s <portnum>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    portnum = argv[1];

    int port = atoi(portnum);
    server = OpenListener(port);

    while(1) {
      struct sockaddr_in addr;
      socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);
      int client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);
      printf("Connection: %s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port));
    }

    close(server);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is just how load balancers work. When you send data, does the server program receive it?

Comment: @user253751 I'm completely new to the concept of load balancers. My understanding was that load balancers just receive the connection and forward it to one of servers (based on whatever algorithm they use). So I thought that the above mentioned client program would be able to connect to the server program running on the EC2 instance, but that's not what's happening. It's instead just connecting to the load balancer

Comment: Forwarding a connection means it connects to the server and pretends you are connected directly to the server.

Comment: @user253751 Well then if I wish to configure SSL passthrough in the NLB how should I do that. Isn't that a direct connection between the client and the server without termination at the load balancer?

Comment: @user253751 Also, in any case - the server DOES receive a connection (from the load balancer and not from the client) so the logs that I've made on the server-side should be visible. That's not happening either

Comment: if you have SSL termination at the load balancer then it's both a SSL terminator and a load balancer at the same time, and the connection to the server is not SSL because you told it not to be

Comment: if the load balancer is not connecting to the server then there is some problem with the load balancer configuration

Comment: You keep saying "The NLB is properly configured" but obviously if something isn't working then it is not property configured. Please provide the details of your NLB configuration. In particular, are you doing TCP passthrough, or are you doing SSL termination at the NLB? Also, do you have client IP preservation enabled in the target group?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what's going on, I'll try to suggest that you need to use Application Load Balancer, because:

Network Load Balancer — this is the distribution of traffic based on network variables, such as IP address and destination ports. It is layer 4 (TCP) and below and is not designed to take into consideration anything at the application layer such as content type, cookie data, custom headers, user location, or the application behavior.

Comment: I don't think ALB is what I'm looking for. The application is just a simple C server running on a port. ALB requires setting up HTTP health checks which need the setup of routes returning a 200 status when pinged. I'm not sure how this would be implemented in the given application. I would further be needing SSL passthrough over TCP connection in the next step, which, again is not possible for an ALB

Comment: @cyborg You're definitely correct on at least the latter. If you don't want TLS-stripping an ALB is not for you (at least it wasn't for *me* :-) ). So... insert standard bonehead question here: you configured your security group to allow any-forwarding for your NLB, *right* ? I'd surely never make such a mistake (lolz), but it never hurts to ask. Besides the obvious (remembering you actually did it) one way to know with reasonable certainty is to check the instance-health in the target group. If the NLB can't reach out to the instances, they're all appear unhealthy.

Comment: @WhozCraig The NLB is properly configured and all the instances are healthy. 
Instead of the C server, I tried to host a simple web application on an apache server on the EC2 instances and everything is working fine. Entering the NLB's URL in the browser opens up the web application from either of the 2 instances associated with the NLB
I guess there is some issue with this particular client and server programs that I've written. Maybe the connection needs to be established in some other way.